# NodeJS and Express - A test is failing me due to auth problems and I can't find the reason

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, mocha.js, passport.js

I have embarked on the adventure of learning node and I have already had the first problems. I am testing with Mocha on the api that I am doing in node, and I have problems with authentication, which is why I am using passport and jwt. The problem comes when I do a test to check a 200 by passing a token to the spike through the body, test, and it returns 401

Here I put the file where I do the auth tests

```
const passport = require ('passport');
// chai is an external library that allows to validate the information of a variable through functions
const chai = require ('chai');

// chai plugin, which allows you to set up servers and make http calls on these servers
const chaiHttp = require ('chai-http');

// In order to do the endpoint tests, you have to call where the backend is located, which is the app.js file
//.app is to call the object that is the server.
const app = require ('../ app'). app;

// to tell chai that you want to use the http plugin it is indicated with the use functionality
chai.use (chaiHttp);

describe ('Auth Test Suite', () => {

    it ('returns 401 when the user is not authorized', (done) => {

        // here chai is told to use the server that is defined in the file
        chai.request (app)

            // Here it is saying to make the http call to the server using the indicated protocol
            .get ('/ team')

            // pick up a function that allows you to interact with the result of the call
            .end ((err, res) => {

                // check that the response is the same as the http status code
                chai.assert.equal (res.status, 401);

                // the test is finished
                done ();
            });
    });

    it ('returns 200 when jwt token is valid', (done) => {

        // here chai is told to use the server that is defined in the file
        chai.request (app)

            // Here it is saying to make the http call to the server using the indicated protocol
            .post ('/ login')

            // pick up a function that allows you to interact with the result of the call
            .end ((err, res) => {

                // once in the post that collects the token, chai is launched again to make another
                // request a get and check the token
                chai.request (app)

                    .get ('/ team')

                    // a header is sent to perform the JWT check
                    .set ('Authorization', `jwt $ {res.body.token}`)

                    .end ((err, res) => {

                        // if the token is valid a 200 is received
                        chai.assert.equal (res.status, 200);

                        // the test is finished
                        done ();
                    });
            });
    });
});
```

Here the app.js

```
// the express library is imported with a require
const express = require ('express');

// the passport library is imported with a require
const passport = require ('passport');

// define the variable that will have the capabilities to use the express features
const app = express ();

// define the connection port that express will use
const port = 3000;

// the function that checks authentications is called
require ('./ auth') (passport);

// the listen object of the const app is called to start listening for connections, otherwise it would be executed
// and it would end up closing, then open keys to the callback function method so that it performs actions
// start the server.
app.listen (port, () => {
    console.log ('Server started on port' + port);
})

// this function is a get request that can be launched from the constant that stores
// the functionalities of express. "req" => request and "res" => response
app.get ('/', (req, res) => {

    // with the ".send" functionality, a response to the request is returned to the client
    res.status (200) .send ('hello world');
});

app.post ('/ login', (req, res) => {
    res.status (200) .json (
        {token: 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0YjoxNTE2MjMXWF0IjoxNTE2MjMXWG2DMXM02MjMXH0IjoxNTE2MjMXWG2DMXM02MJMXH0IjoxNTE2MjMXMXWG2DMXMJ2MJMX2DXMXM02MjWG
    )
});


app.get ('/ team',
    // when using this route it will be verified whoever uses it has a JWT, it is a middleware
    passport.authenticate ('jwt', {session: false}),
    (req, res) => {

        res.status (200) .send ('hello world');

    });

app.post ('/ team / pokemons', (req, res) => {
    res.status (200) .send ('hello world');
});

app.delete ('/ team / pokemons /: pokeid', (req, res) => {
    res.status (200) .send ('hello world');
});

app.put ('/ team', (req, res) => {
    res.status (200) .send ('hello world');
});


module.exports.app = app;
```

and finally the auth file in which I have passport and JWT

```
// imported library to use passport. Strategy is used to create an authentication strategy (I think so)
const jwtStrategy = require ('passport-jwt'). Strategy;

const extractJwt = require ('passport-jwt'). ExtractJwt;

// This function is exported to which passport is passed by parameter
module.exports = passport => {

     // this would create a JSON object that would be the strategy to use
     const opts = {
         // this line specifies where the jwt will be taken from when making the request
         jwtFromRequest: extractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme ("JWT"),
         secretOrKey: 'secretPassword'
     }
     // Here passport is instructed to use the strategy created previously, and a function is entered inside it
     // result, to do checks
     passport.use (new jwtStrategy (opts, (decoded, done) => {
         console.log ('decoded jwt', decoded);
         return done (null, false);
     }));
}
```

at the end of the test I get an error on line 59 of the test files (`chai.assert.equal(res.status, 200);`), specifically the second test that jwt tests but I don't understand where the error is. I attach a photo of the test results.
[test result][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVMTg.jpg

Finally, I feel my level of English, I am bad at the language and I have used the translator to ask this question

Comment: I've never seen spaces in route paths before, are you certain that doesn't cause any issues?

Comment: no, I think there are spaces to copy and paste, in my code I don't have them